# issue while creating Kubernetes Dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

I am not able to create Kubernetes Dashboard.

I am following the steps mentioned in Kubernetes official [website](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/):

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml

secret "kubernetes-dashboard-certs" created
serviceaccount "kubernetes-dashboard" created
service "kubernetes-dashboard" created
```

> Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml": Role in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Role: no kind "Role" is registered for version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1" Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml": RoleBinding in version "v1" cannot be handled as a RoleBinding: no kind "RoleBinding" is registered for version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1" Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml":Deployment in version "v1beta2" cannot be handled as a Deployment: no kind "Deployment" is registered for version "apps/v1beta2"

**Our Kubernetes version is as follows:**

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7", GitVersion:"v1.7.2", GitCommit:"922a86cfcd65915a9b2f69f3f193b8907d741d9c", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-07-21T08:23:22Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7", GitVersion:"v1.7.12", GitCommit:"3bda299a6414b4866f179921610d6738206a18fe", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-12-29T08:39:49Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I have not been able to find an appropriate solution for this issue.

Comment: Up need to upgrade your kubernetes version.

Comment: For kubernetes 1.7.x version, use this https://v1-7.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/

Answer (score 1):

You need a cluster with RBAC enabled, otherwise the installation will fail because it can't find the `Role` kind of object. To enable RBAC, start the apiserver with `--authorization-mode=RBAC`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Please can you share the steps on how to do the same?

Comment: the same what? Just restart the apiserver with --authorization-mode=RBAC

Comment: It depends a lot on how you created the cluster.